# Grammatik in "Ein gutes Foto, finde ich"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Ich stoße auf ein Foto und finde es ein gutes. Wäre es grammatisch, eines der Folgenden zu sagen?

> (a) Ein gutes Foto, finde ich.
>
> (b) Ein gutes Foto, ich finde.

Comment: (a) ist korrekt. (b) ist falsch herum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Im Zweifelsfall an den Hauptsatz (Aussagesatz) denken: 
"Das finite Verb steht *an zweiter Stelle* (der Satzglieder, nicht der Wörter)."

Also ergibt sich

> (a)[Ein gutes Foto,]  [**finde**]  [ich]. -> Verb an **2.** Position: korrekt. 
>   (b)[Ein gutes Foto,]  [ich]  [**finde**]. -> Verb an **3.** Position: falsch.

Das klappt auch in der vereinfachten Version:

> (a')[Das]  [**finde**]  [ich]. -> Verb an 2. Position.

Haupstätze kann man auch mehrere hintereinanderhängen:

> [[Ich] [**finde**]], [[das]  [**ist**]  [ein gutes Foto]].

Im Nebensatz steht das Verb dagegen *hinten*:

> [[Ich]  [**finde**]], [[dass]  [das]  [ein gutes Foto]  [**ist**]].

---

*Zur Ergänzung:*

Für Fragesätze gibt es zwei Varianten:

Ohne Fragewort ("Entscheidungsfragen") wandert das finite Verb an die erste Stelle:

> [**Findest**] [du]....?

Mit Fragewort ("Ergänzungsfragen") bleibt das finite Verb an 2. Stelle:

> [Wie]  [findest]  [du]....?